# Authorize.net iOS SDK integration issue, always failed request

Tags: ios, sdk, authorize.net

Here is my code used to register and log in to gateway

```
    -(void)registerDevice
{
    MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest *registrationRequest=[MobileDeviceRegistrationRequest mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];
    registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name=self.APIName;
    registrationRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = self.APITransactionKey;
    registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDescription=@"iPhone";
    registrationRequest.mobileDevice.mobileDeviceId=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST];
    AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];
    [an setDelegate:self];

    [an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:registrationRequest];

}

- (void) loginToGateway
{
    MobileDeviceLoginRequest *mobileDeviceLoginRequest = [MobileDeviceLoginRequest mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
    mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = self.APIName;
    mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.password = self.APITransactionKey;
    NSLog(@"UIDevice =%@",[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]);
    mobileDeviceLoginRequest.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId =
    [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    [AuthNet authNetWithEnvironment:ENV_TEST];
    AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];
    [an setDelegate:self];
    [an mobileDeviceLoginRequest: mobileDeviceLoginRequest];
}
```

I am trying to integrate the Authorize.net payment gateway in an iOS application. However everytime I make the request, I get this single response.

```
2015-08-22 16:41:41.741 Authorizetest[3193:261060] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
2015-08-22 16:41:42.754 Authorizetest[3193:261060] Mobile Device Registration Response
2015-08-22 16:41:42.754 Authorizetest[3193:261060] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mobileDeviceRegistrationResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"><messages><resultCode>Error</resultCode><message><code>E00007</code><text>User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.</text></message></messages></mobileDeviceRegistrationResponse>
namespace warning : xmlns: URI AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd is not absolute
ttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd"
```

the error code is E00007 and message is "authentication failed due to invalid authentication values."

Can someone please guide me on what wrong I'm doing here.

Thanks

Comment: did you approved particular device from the send-box ?

Comment: @iAshish - do I need to approve all the devices that I want to use ?

Comment: Yes brother. You must have to approve all devices.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate a payment gateway whereby individuals can pay for my products from their mobile devices. I'm not getting how they will register their devices before they could pay for it. Can you please elaborate it a little. I'm confused.

Comment: Ok, One of the Authorize.net developer replied me like this. I am adding it in the answer.